Meaning of 拵えた here
From Kokoro chapter 20:

先生はむしろ機嫌がよかった。しかし奥さんの調子はさらによかった。今しがた奥さんの美しい眼のうちに溜った涙の光と、それから黒い眉毛の根に寄せられた八の字を記憶していた私は、その変化を異常なものとして注意深く眺めた。もしそれが詐りでなかったならば、（実際それは詐りとは思えなかったが）、今までの奥さんの訴えは感傷{センチメント}を玩ぶためにとくに私を相手に拵えた、徒らな女性の遊戯と取れない事もなかった。

In the last line, it seems like the narrator suspected Sensei's wife played with his gullibleness in the earlier conversation, judging from her sudden change in mood.
I am not sure about the meaning of 拵えた in 私を相手に拵えた. I think it means something like 私を相手にした. What is the subject of this verb?
Also, I am not sure about the meaning of 訴え.


This 訴え is "appeal" or "complaint", and 今までの奥さんの訴え refers to whatever she was just saying. 眼のうちに溜った涙の光 and 眉毛の根に寄せられた八の字 indicates that she was emotionally appealing something to the protagonist just moments ago.

The subject of 拵えた is 奥さん. 私を相手に is the AをBに construction.

Here, 奥さん's sudden change in mood led the protagonist to realize that her emotional appeals to him was possibly crocodile tears.



訴えは(彼女が)私を相手に拵えたものだ。
As for the appeal, it's something she crafted with me as the target.
今までの奥さんの訴えは感傷を玩ぶためにとくに私を相手に拵えた、徒らな女性の遊戯と取れない事もなかった。
Her appeals up until now may have been taken as a mischievous "womanly tactic" she had crafted, particularly targeting me to toy with my sentiments.

